# C++ struct, function can't print smallest diameter

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

This is my code so far the problem I am having is with it printing out the smallest diameter of the planet.
**Update Code**....and still don't work...

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

struct Planet
{
  string name;
  int distanceSun;
  int diameter;
  int mass;
};

int PrintPlanet(Planet  planet)
{
   cout << "Name: " << planet.name << endl;
   cout << "Distance to the sun: " << planet.distanceSun << endl;
   cout << "Diameter: " << planet.diameter << endl;
   cout << "Mass: " << planet.mass << endl;

   return 0;
}

int FindSmallestDiameter(Planet * arr, int n)
{   
   int resultSmallest = INT_MAX;

   for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
   {
       if(arr[j].diameter < arr[resultSmallest].diameter)
       {
           resultSmallest = j;
       }
   }
   return resultSmallest;
}       

int main()
{
   struct Planet * planet;
   int numberPlanet;
   cout << "Enter a value for planets: ";
   cin >> numberPlanet;

   planet = new Planet[numberPlanet];   
   int enterSelection;

  do
  {
     cout << "Enter selection: \n" <<
         "1. Print the planet with the smallest diameter\n" << 
         "0. Exit progrma\n";
     cin >> enterSelection;

     switch(enterSelection)
     {
        case 1:
        {
           int heaviest = FindHeaviestPlanet(planet, numberPlanet);
           if (heaviest < 0)
           {
              cout << "No planet defined.\n";
           }
           else
           {
              cout << "Heaviest planet: \n";
              PrintPlanet(planet[heaviest]);
           }
       }
       break;
   }
```

'
When in the menu set the print command on the planet with the smaller diameter console print:
Name:
Distance to the sun: 0 
Diameter: 0
Mass: 0

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what were you expecting the smallest diameter to be?

Comment: Please use `const` e.g. `int PrintPlanet(Planet  planet)` -> `int PrintPlanet(const Planet&  planet)`

Comment: you use resultSmallest as index to arr and set it to INT_MAX, which can lead to unexpected resutls. notice that you pass numberPlanet as input to FindSmallestDiameter which represent the array 'arr' size. this value arrive from input and can be smaller than INT_MAX...

Comment: Should both diameter and mass be unsigned?

Comment: Perhaps `std::vector` would be better

Comment: where's the switch in your code ?? comething is missing here

Comment: `case 1` ... has the grammar changed, or is there a `switch` missing?

Comment: Perhaps getting it to compile would be a good start

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: ... and get it to compile!

Comment: That code has so many problems ... Start step-by-step to understand what is going on. Don't implement everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the missing code in `main()`, the syntactic errors there, and the way you could populate the planets, your search function `FindSmallestDiameter()` will never work:

- you start with `resultSmallest = INT_MAX`.  This is a very very large number
- then you start your loop with `j=1` (normally array indexing startw with 0)
- then you try to access `arr[resultSmallest].diameter`,  which is out of bounds, and causes undefined behaviour. It could cause havoc or segmentation faults, but it could also return a random number, or even 0.
- Note that this function will never return a negative number, even if the planet array is empty. So your message "No planet defined" will never be displayed.  Even worse, if no planet is defined, you'll return `INT_MAX`, which could cause your code in `main()` to (try to) access further elements out of bounds.

Possible correction:

```
int FindSmallestDiameter(Planet * arr, int n)
{   
   if (n==0) 
       return -1;    // handle special case first
   else {  
       int resultSmallest = 0;  // let's suppose the smallest is the first element

       for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) { // then it makes sense to loop starting with the second
          if(arr[j].diameter < arr[resultSmallest].diameter) // and challenge the current smalest
              resultSmallest = j;
       }
       return resultSmallest; 
    } 
}
```

Or a [shorter one](http://ideone.com/5WTExT), using standard algorithm [`std::min_element()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/):

```
int FindSmallestDiameter(Planet * arr, int n)
{   
   return n==0 ? -1 : std::min_element(arr,arr+n,[](const Planet &a,const Planet &b)->bool {return a.diameter<b.diameter;})-arr;
}
```

Comment: I think that `j=1` is ok if `int resultSmallest = INT_MAX;` was `int resultSmallest = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with the following function:

```
 Planet FindSmallestDiameter(Planet * arr, int n)
 {
    Planet smallestDiameter = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       if (smallestDiameter.diameter < arr[i].diameter)
       {
          smallestDiameter = arr[i];
       }
    }
    return smallestDiameter;
 }
```